# Find conserved quantities with respect to parameters in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, parametrization, steady-state

I have a standard, steady-state convection-diffusion PDE given as:
$$
-p_1 \nabla^2 c(x,y) + \vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla}c(x,y) = f(x,y)
$$
With $\vec{v} := \frac{p_2}{\sqrt{2}}\langle 1,1\rangle$. Here $p_1$ and $p_2$ are parameters each on their own domain (i.e. $p_1 \in [a,b]$ and $p_2 \in [c,d]$, for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$). Given the solution is known, is there a way to define a functional on the solution, $F[c(x,y;p_1,p_2),x,y]$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial p_1} = 0 \:\:\: \text{but}\:\:\: \frac{\partial F}{\partial p_2} \neq 0 \:\:\: \text{and vice versa}
$$
This boils down to finding conserved quantities on $c(x,y)$ with respect to my parameters. I figured if this is possible this might use some form of a variational principle, but I can't quite figure out how that would be implemented. On the other hand, if this is not possible, could someone explain why?

Comment: You might clarify your second term. As it stands it appears to involve a vector (a gradient of $c$) while everything else is scalar.

Comment: My mistake. I have fixed the error now

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of such a functional but perhaps this can be of help on the way. To get a conservation law,  first consider:
$$-p_1 \nabla^2 c + \vec{v} \cdot \nabla c =0$$
Now, assuming $p_1$, $p_2$, and $\vec{v}$ are constants we can rewrite the equation as :

$$- \nabla \cdot \nabla (p_1 c) +  \nabla \cdot (\vec{v} c) = 0$$

This is because:
$$ \nabla \cdot (\vec{v} c) =  c \nabla \cdot \vec{v}+\vec{v} \cdot \nabla c $$

and since $\vec{v}$ is constant we have:
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{v}=0$$

Collecting terms we get:
$$ \nabla \cdot (-p_1 \nabla  c + \vec{v} c) = 0$$

We can now integrate over a control volume and get:

$$\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot (-p_1 \nabla  c + \vec{v} c) dV= 0$$
Using Gauss theorem we get:
$$\int_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{n} \cdot (-p_1 \nabla  c + \vec{v} c) dS= 0$$
where $\mathbf{n}$ is the normal vector on the control surface $\partial \Omega$ enclosing $\Omega$. This means that the quantity:
$$-p_1 \nabla  c + \vec{v} c$$ is a conserved quantity in terms of all of $p_1$, $p_2$, $c$.

However, you also have $f$ injecting "mass" into the control volume which makes the equation as a whole non-conservative.
You can write this on conservative form even in this case provided you can find a $\vec{q}$ such that
$f=\nabla \cdot \vec{q}$  since then the equation can be written:
$$ \nabla \cdot (-p_1 \nabla  c + \vec{v} c-\vec{q}) = 0$$
So that now:
$$-p_1 \nabla  c + \vec{v} c-\vec{q}$$
is the conserved quantity.